# D3 - Returning a table row to original bgcolor on mouseout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onmouseout

Apologies for newbie question, but I'm trying to do the following using d3:

1) render alternating rows as grey and white (zebra style)
2) highlight rows on a mouseover event
3) RETURN the row to its original state on mouseout

I've done this via the following code, which works fine except for returning the rows to their original color on mouseout. Instead, it just renders every row as #c4c4c4 on mouseout

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    data(states)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .style("background-color", function(d, i) {
       if (i%2===0){return "#fff";}else{return "#c4c4c4";}
      });


var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
     .on("mouseover", function(){
         d3.select(this).style("background-color", "yellow");})
     .on("mouseout", function(){
         d3.select(this).style("background-color", function(d,i) {
            if (i % 2 === 0){
               return "#fff";
             }
            else {
               return "#c4c4c4";
             }
        }
    )}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you re-select the `this` element, that becomes the selection from which the `i` index is determined for the inner (style) callback function.  You want the `i` index from the mouseout event handling function:

```
 .on("mouseout", function(d,i){ //correct index is passed here!

     d3.select(this).style("background-color", function(d2,j) {
                            //d2 will be the same as d, but j will always be 0
                            //since d3.select(this) only has one element
        if (i % 2 === 0){
           return "#fff";
         }
        else {
           return "#c4c4c4";
         }
    } )
 });
```

You don't really need to declare the parameters `d2` and `j`, since they're never used -- I just included them for clarity.

By the way, you can do both of these effects with CSS:

```
tr:nth-of-type(2n) { /* even rows */
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}
tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) { /* odd rows */
  background-color: #fff;
}
tr:hover { /* mouseover */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Note that in CSS, elements are numbered starting with 1, so the first row is considered an odd row.

Comment: this helped tremendously, thank you. now how to make both the relevant ROW and the COLUMN of a table highlight on mouseover??? my challenge is to accomplish it using d3.js if possible. back to the drawing board...

Comment: To find the column, you could either actually create `<col>` elements at the top of your table, and set their background color, or use the `td:nth-of-type()` syntax to select all the table cells at a given index in a row.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can do this with CSS, because `<col>` groups never trigger the `:hover` effect: http://fiddle.jshell.net/WV4wG/  But you can grab the index value in a mouseover function, and select the correct cells or column with d3. Just remember that you have to add 1 to switch from the Javascript (0-based) index to the CSS (1-based) index.

Comment: Example of using CSS `nth-of-type` selectors in combination with d3 index values in an event-handling function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21470867/3128209