# Calling tooltip in context of d3 visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have a visualization and I'm trying to use d3.tip() - https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/docs/initializing-tooltips.md#d3tip

This is my code-

```
            this.svg = d3.select(".timechart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
            .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll('.point')
                .data(newData)
                .enter()
                .append("svg:circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d,i){ 
                    var date = d["date"].match(/(\d+)/g);
                    date = new Date(date[2], date[0], date[1]);
                    return xScale(date);
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d,i){
                    var quantitySold = yScale(d["quantity-sold"]);
                    return quantitySold;
                })
                .attr("fill", "red")
                .attr("r", 4)
                .on("mouseover", function(d){
                    tooltip.show();
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(d){
                    tooltip.hide();
                });


            var tooltip = d3.tip()
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .offset([0,5])
                .html(function(d){
                    console.log(d);
                    return "<strong> 20 </strong>";
                });

            svg.call(tooltip);
```

The console.log(d) gives me undefined, when it should give me the datum.

Why?

I also realize - I'm not sure what code I should post here to help - just let me know what would be useful.

Comment: You must not call it like that. Try this `return console.log("<strong> 20 </strong>")`

Comment: You should post the smallest program that is fully functional. Your problem could be anywhere, so we need to see the <html>, <head>, <script> etc. Then folks can experiment and know they have a valid solution before answering.

Comment: You haven't bound any data to the element that you're attaching the tooltip to.

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip library that you're using ([d3.tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip)) creates a single html tooltip for the entire visualization.  The data for a particular element is passed to the tooltip using the tooltip's `.show(d,i)` method.

[This example from the plug-in's creator](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) shows how it is supposed to work.  In particular, note that the show and hide methods are given directly as parameters to the `.on(event, function)` method of the rectangle selection:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
 /* ... */
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

When the event occurs, d3 will therefore call these methods **and pass the data object to them as a parameter**.

In contrast, in your code:

```
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            tooltip.show();
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
            tooltip.hide();
        });
```

d3 will pass the data to your anonymous function, but you do not pass it on to the show/hide functions.  So the data is undefined when the tooltip's `show` function tries to set the html content of the tooltip.

If you find that all confusing still, you might appreciate [this write-up about passing functions as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21421101/3128209).

Finally, although it isn't your main problem right now, you should be defining the tooltip before assigning its functions to an event handler.  If you tried to do `.on('mouseover', tooltip.show)` before defining `tooltip`, you would get an error.  You only avoided it by wrapping that function call in another function.