# How do I select a class dynamically in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I using the following code for my select function

```
quadrants = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (var i in quadrants) 
{
    svgContainer.append("g").attr("class", quadrants[i]);
    var group = d3.select(function () {return "." + quadrants[i]});

    group.append("polygon");
    .....
}
```

This does not work since the value of group is 'function () {return "." + quadrants[i]'. 
How do I fix it so that group selects ".a", ".b" and so on?

Comment: Is it a typo or are you not closing the `{`?

Comment: Sorry thats a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `{`

Also, you do not need to use a function, the following code works:

```
quadrants = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (var i in quadrants) 
{
    //svgContainer.append("g").attr("class", quadrants[i]);
    var group = d3.selectAll('.'+quadrants[i]);
    group.text(function(){return i});
}
```

In fact using a function does not make sense. The role of the function would be to compute dynamically the selector from a variable. However there is nothing that gets passed to the function when using `d3.select` or `d3.selectAll`.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hTnJq/1/

Comment: or `var group = d3.select('.' + quadrants[i]);`

Comment: Thank you so much... That solved it. Can you tell me why I can't use a function in select(). I am new to JS and D3 so this may be a noob question.

Comment: `select` will also work, but it will only select the first item of all corresponding to the selector. Which is not what you usually want with classes. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/hTnJq/2/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use a function in a `d3.select` or `d3.selectAll` statement because you don't have any elements yet to use as the source of the function's `d` and `i` values.  You can only use a function for the select statement if it is a [*nested selection* like `selection.selectAll( function )`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select), in which case the *parent element*'s data and index values are used in the function.

However, there is also a much more elegant way to do what you're trying to do, by using d3 [data joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/):

```
quadrants = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

var group = svgContainer.selectAll("g") //define a selection of <g> elements
               .data( quadrants ); //declare that you want one <g> 
                                   //for each value in quadrants

group.enter() //get the placeholder selection for the data objects
              //that don't have matching elements yet
     .append('g') //create the elements for each placeholder
     .attr("class", function(d,i) {
               //make the class a function of the data 
               //(which is the value from the quadrants array)
              return d;
          });

group.append("polygon");  //add a polygon to *each* <g> element
```

Comment: P.S.  You might also find [this longer discussion on anonymous functions-as-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358027/how-are-input-parameters-filled-in-javascript-method-chains/21421101#21421101) to be useful.