# Inline D3 sparklines in a table alongside text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Say if there is a table like this:

```
var data = [
    ['Orange', 'Orange', [6,3,3,2,5]],
    ['Apple', 'Red', [6,2,6,5,5]],
    ['Grape', 'Purple', [9,1,2,3,1]]
]
```

I'd like the strings to represented as strings, but the number array represented as a D3 line chart. If it's just text that I care about, I can `selectAll` `td` elements and insert some text.

```
var tcells = trows
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d, i) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function(d, i) { return d; });
```

The 3rd column is text so I'd like to update it with graphs or alternatively append another column of graphs. Say `lines` is a function that creates a line graph, I would like to call `lines()` as it passes data from the 3rd column for **each** row.

```
trows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) {return d[2]}) // scope out data from 3rd column
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    //.call(lines([3,8,2,5,8,4])); // this works
    .call(lines);                // this doesn't
```

My D3 knowledge is spotty so I am not clear on how the data and the selection are passed.

Here is the full code:
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tokestermw/Lgq6ct9f/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the [`selection.call(func)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-call) method with the [`selection.each(func)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) method.

`call` is a convenience method for calling functions that accept the *selection* as a whole as a parameter. `trows.call(lines)` is equivalent to `lines(trows)`, except that it can be part of a method chain.

`each` is used to call a function once for each element in the selection, passing the data and index as parameters.

As for why `trows.call(lines([3,8,2,5,8,4]))` "works", well it only sort-of works.  You're calling the function `lines`, with the hard-coded data array, but that function doesn't return anything, so there is nothing to `call` on the selection itself.  (If you don't understand the difference, you might [find this answer useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358027/how-are-input-parameters-filled-in-javascript-method-chains/21421101#21421101).)

Your method also currently only appends the line graph to the body, it doesn't insert it into the table.  You have the following code that you acknowledge doesn't work:

```
// dynamic selection doesn't
this.append("td").append('svg')
    .attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
    .append('path').attr('class','line')
    .datum(data).attr('d', line);
```

There are a few reasons that is failing:

- in the context you're calling the function, with `lines([3,8,2,5,8,4])` being called directly, the `this` value will not be set, so will point to the window object;
- even if you were calling the function with an `each` method (which sets the `this` value), `this` would point to the DOM node, not a selection that you can call d3 methods for;
- except in your specific case, it wouldn't even point to a DOM node, because you're calling it from an `enter()` selection in which you haven't appended the new nodes yet.

In summary, to get things working:

1. In the main program, use `each` to call your `lines` function, after creating your new `<td>` elements:

   ```
   trows.selectAll("td.graph")  
        //use a class so you don't re-select the existing <td> elements
     .data(function(d) {return [d[2]];})
        // the value returned by a data function must always be an array
        // containing data objects for each new element you create -- 
        // you only want one element containing the entire data array, 
        // not individual elements for each number, so wrap it in another array
     .enter()
       .append("td")
       .attr("class", "graph")
       .each(lines);
   ```
2. In the `lines` function, re-select the `this` element (which will now point to the just-created `<td>`), and append your sparkline SVG to it:

   ```
   d3.select(this).append('svg')
           .attr('width', width)
           .attr('height', height)
        .append('path')
           .attr('class','line')
           .datum(data)
           .attr('d', line);
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq6ct9f/9/
(with some other clean-up so you don't have a function definition in the middle of your main program)