# D3.js: Pass arguments through method chaining

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I don't completely understand how to use method chaining with functions. Below are some cases

Expected Case

```
var dataset = [ 5, 10];

function count(d) {
  return "I can count up to " + d ; 
}
            d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("p")
                .text(count);
```

**Output**

```
I can count up to 5

I can count up to 10
```

What I don't get is this output from a modified count function

```
function count(d, a) {
  return "I can count up to " + d + a ; 
}
```

**Output**

```
I can count up to 50

I can count up to 101
```

Read this post but I'm still missing something. Should I just reread it?

[How are input parameters filled in javascript method chains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358027/how-are-input-parameters-filled-in-javascript-method-chains)

Comment: Apparently, the index of the element is passed as the second parameter. So, the first time you get 50 which is actually '5' + '0' and then 101 is '10' + '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function in `d3.js` `.text` its signature is:

```
.text(function(datum, index){

 });
```

So:

```
return "I can count up to " + d + a ;
```

means:

```
return string + datum + index.
```

Finally, with Javascript, when you start with a string first, everything is coerced into a string so the `d + a` concatenates 5 and 0 and then 10 and 1.